# Coreplot : Custom space between two points in graph

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

How do i implement custom space between data points in graph as shown in pic below, Objective c is used

[image]

```
CGRect bounds = self.graphView.bounds;
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
self.graphView.hostedGraph = graph;

// graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    += 25.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   += 55.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom += 70.0;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  += 20.0;

// Grid line styles
CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
majorGridLineStyle.lineColor =  self.line1Color;
//[[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.2] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];

CPTLineCap *lineCap = [CPTLineCap sweptArrowPlotLineCap];
lineCap.size = CGSizeMake(15.0, 15.0);

// Axes
// Label x axis with a fixed interval policy
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;

x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInt(1);
x.labelingOrigin = @(0).decimalValue;
int i = 0;
NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *titleLocations = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSMutableDictionary *v in self.values)
{
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[[v valueForKey:@"x"] toDDMMYYYYString] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] decimalValue];
    newLabel.offset          = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
    newLabel.rotation = M_PI/2.0f;
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
    [titleLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i ]];
    i++;
}

x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:titleLocations];
x.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
x.axisConstraints             = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

x.labelingOrigin = @(0).decimalValue;
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = [NSDecimalNumber zero].decimalValue;
lineCap.lineStyle = x.axisLineStyle;
lineCap.fill      = [CPTFill fillWithColor:lineCap.lineStyle.lineColor];

// Label y with an automatic label policy.
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
y.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
y.axisConstraints             = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
y.labelOffset                 = 10.0;
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;`
```

I have give the following xrange and yrange

```
if(self.values.count>5){
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(self.pt) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( MAX(self.values.count, 6))];
        plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(min) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(max)];
}else{
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(self.pt) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( MIN(self.values.count, 3))];
        plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(min) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(max)];
}
```

Comment: show your code, where you count xAxis

Comment: Hi, i'm able to plot with equal distant between data points, any method in coreplot to have custom gap/space between two data points?

Answer (score 0):

The datasource provides both the x- and y-values for each data point. The values don't have to be evenly spaced. The axis labels are controlled by the `labelingPolicy`. Use the locations provided or "none" policy to provide your own label and/or tick locations.

Comment: Hi Eric, i have added code reference could you please guide me, i couldn't get it.

Comment: Set the `newLabel.tickLocation` to the value corresponding to the x-value of the data point, not the index. Use the same conversion you use in the datasource to compute the x-value from the `values` dictionary.

Comment: Hi Eric, i tried but the distance between two data points remain same/equidistant could you provide a simple code reference would be helpful. TIA

Comment: Look at the "Axis Labeling Policy" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app included with Core Plot.

Comment: Hi Eric, I'm able to create a gap or space between the labels but not on the plots or data points.

Comment: The datasource sends both the x- and y-values to the plot. These can be anything you want, although any point outside the x- and y-ranges on the plot space will be invisible. There's no requirement that the data points at successive data indexes need to be evenly spaced. It's hard to offer specific advice without knowing how the data is stored. The code shown in the question assumes that the x-values will correspond with the data index. You have to break that assumption.